# How to write IIF condition in Oracle

Tags: ssms, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do we write **IIF** condition in Oracle.

```
IIF(ItemType = '-1' , (Select CAST(CAST(ConfigXml as XML).query('data(/configurations/config/itemtypeid)') as nvarchar (64)) from EmailCaptureConfig where OwnerID = 142 and ConfigID = 1), ActionObjecttype) as ActionObject
```

I need to convert the above IIF into **ORACLE** but am unable to do so. How do we go forward with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to this:

```
decode(ItemType, '-1' , (Select CAST(CAST(ConfigXml as XML).query('data(/configurations/config/itemtypeid)') as nvarchar (64)) from EmailCaptureConfig where OwnerID = 142 and ConfigID = 1), ActionObjecttype) as ActionObject
```

Obviously the xml datatype works differently in Oracle than Microsoft.

Comment: decode(ItemType, '-1' , (Select EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ConfigXml), '/configurations/config/itemtypeid') from EmailCaptureConfig where OwnerID = 142 and ConfigID = 1), ActionObjecttype) as ActionObject,